# Why is ThreadPoolExecutor freezing?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

i am using ThreadPoolExecutor to get a lot of requests from websites quickly, but sometimes, maybe 1 in 5 times, ThreadPoolExecutor finishes running all of the thread functions and then just freezes without moving on to the rest of my code. I need this to be reliable for a project i'm working on.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import ballotpedialinks as bl

data =[[link,0],[link,1],[link,2]...[link,500]]

def threadFunction(data):
    page = data[0]
    counter = data[1]
    a = bl.checkLink(page)
    print(a[0])
    if a[0] == '':
        links = bl.generateNewLinks(page,state)
        for link in links:
            a = bl.checkLink(link)
            if a[0] != '':
                print(f'{a[0]} is a fixed link')
                break

def quickRun(threads):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(threads) as pool:
        pool.map(threadFunction,data[0:-1])

quickRun(32)

print('scraper complete')
```

this is basically what i'm doing but thread function is sending requests to websites. executor finishes all the tasks i give it but sometimes it just freezes once its done. Is there anything i can do to make executor not freeze?

Comment: Is it possible that these requests being sent to websites are hanging because some type of response is expected?

Comment: no because it finishes the requests process before freezing

Comment: What do you mean by 'it freezer's? Can you provide more details with respect to current behavior?

Comment: it finishes executing the code on the last thread and then it stops and does not run any code after that. if i were to put a print('finished') after the code in the example it wouldn't run it @RodrigoLaguna

Comment: To provide evidence to our confusion: I just ran your example and everything works as intended, all numbers print and if I add a print after the `quickRun` call it will print just fine. So, it leads me to believe that the problematic code is in your original code which is making requests to websites.

Comment: ok i edited it to contain my original code, there is a lot of missing stuff though, do you need anything else added? ballotpedialinks is one of my modules and everything in it works reliably @VoidTwo

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ballotpedialinks`, but is there potentially an area where the code might hang? For example when calling `bl.checkLink()`?

Comment: not really, its all able to handle any exceptions. i just double checked it and pretty much every step would raise an exception if there was a problem. since i believe ThreadPoolExecutor handles exceptions by ending the thread it couldn't be that right? it also only freezes maybe 1/5 times even when i give it the same initial links to run on @VoidTwo

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) it appears that if an exception is raised, the value needs to be retrieved first. Maybe try modifying your mapping line to be `_ = pool.map(threadFunction,data[0:-1])`. Edit: This is the example the documentation provides: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Comment: ok i'll give it a shot, it might take a while to test because the error is normally kinda rare

Comment: The docs for ThreadPool.map say this: "If a func call raises an exception, then that exception will be raised when its value is retrieved from the iterator."  You aren't using the iterator at all, so you are never retrieving any value.  So if one of the function calls raises an exception, I suppose the behavior is undefined.  Perhaps that is your real problem?